# How do I skip to a specific input line in Perl?

Tags: perl, loops

I want to skip to the first line that contains "include".

```
<> until /include/;
```

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The match operator defaults to using `$_` but the `<>` operator doesn't store into `$_` by default unless it is used in a while loop so nothing is being stored in `$_`.

From `perldoc perlop`:

```
   I/O Operators
   ...

   Ordinarily you must assign the returned value to a variable, but there
   is one situation where an automatic assignment happens.  If and only if
   the input symbol is the only thing inside the conditional of a "while"
   statement (even if disguised as a "for(;;)" loop), the value is auto‐
   matically assigned to the global variable $_, destroying whatever was
   there previously.  (This may seem like an odd thing to you, but you’ll
   use the construct in almost every Perl script you write.)  The $_ vari‐
   able is not implicitly localized.  You’ll have to put a "local $_;"
   before the loop if you want that to happen.

   The following lines are equivalent:

       while (defined($_ = )) { print; }
       while ($_ = ) { print; }
       while () { print; }
       for (;;) { print; }
       print while defined($_ = );
       print while ($_ = );
       print while ;

   This also behaves similarly, but avoids $_ :

       while (my $line = ) { print $line }
```

Comment: Me neither.  Why does <> behave differently when it's not in a while loop?

Comment: It is just a shortcut so that you can say "while (<>) { ... }" instead of "while (defined($_ = <>)) { ... }".

Answer (score 4):

`<>` is only magic in a `while(<>)` construct.  Otherwise it does not assign to `$_`, so the `/include/` regular expression has nothing to match against.  If you ran this with `-w` Perl would tell you:

```
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at ....
```

You can fix this with:

```
$_ = <> until /include/;
```

To avoid the warning:

```
while(<>)
{
    last if /include/;
}
```